# Processing android mode installation error: could not move mode "Android Mode" to the sketchbook

Tags: android, processing

I have just downloaded Processing 2.0 and trying to install the Android mode from "Mode Manager". But while installing I am having an error says: 'could not move mode "Android Mode" to the sketchbook'. 
How can I get rid from this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed to download Android mode manually.
The steps are given below:

1. Download "Android Mode" zip file from [here](http://www.blurrypaths.com/post/52573899794/processing-2-0-modes-download-links).
2. Unzip the downloaded "Android Mode" in the directory "C:/ Users/User/My Documents/Processing/modes/".
3. Restart Processing.

For more information, visit [here](https://forum.processing.org/topic/add-mode-in-processing-2-0b9).

Comment: @shoanAshraf do you have any idea as to why I can't download it anyway, I don't even have the option appear as as something I can download